# How to hide the viewers from see each other in the same google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, member-hiding

I have a google sheet file that needed to share with multiple co-workers, but I don't need them to know who and how many people I share the file with. I'm really tired of making a copy of multiple files to share with each person. So, is there any way I can hide them? It would help me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think if you share the sheet with `Restricted` mode, there is no way.
But with `Anyone with the link` mode, the icons show as `Anonymous` icons (like animals).
Is this not enough?

[image]